# Is there a way to call synchronously asynchronous functions from bash script?

Tags: bash, function, asynchronous, synchronous

I have some function in a bash script that involve sending http post requests. After I call them I store the results, and I check the disk usage.

How can I make sure that the du -sh I use run only after the http request is done?

I send a lot of http requests (1M), so checking everytime for the header code is a bit inefficient.

Does anyone here have an idea?

If I don't find anything elegant, is there a difference between:

```
#! /bin/bash
http_req_1 1000000
sleep X
Size=$(du -sh ./PATH)
http_req_2 1000001
...
```

Or:

```
#! bin/bash
function http_req {
   local loop_num=1$
   for i in $(eval echo "1...$loop_num")
     do
        curl ...
     done
   sleep X
   SIZE=$(du -sh)
}
http_req 1000000
http_req 1000001
....
```

?

I use CentOS 7.

Thank you!